# how to set password expiry date in jsp/servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating the web project with username+password.In this project how to set password expiration ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: my project basically based on jsp/servlet.Then i set the password expiration date in main page(username+password page).how to possible?

Comment: Are you want to invalidate session from JSP Page? if yes session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10); might help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cookie to keep track of the logged in user the cookies setMaxAge() method.
After that you just set the cookie in your servlet or service or what you are using.

Comment: I still don't know what you want but set a cookie in the Servlet with `Cookie cookie = new Cookie("CName","Cookie Value");
  cookie.setMaxAge(100);
  response.addCookie(cookie);`

Answer (score 1):

Persist your password somewhere may be in `database` (Recommended) and then on each `login validate` the password based on your expiration criteria and if expires prompt user to change it.

**EDIT:**

Below is some code snippet . you can refer this to implement above.

```
public class SerializationPassword {
 public void saveDetails(User lUser) throws IOException{


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("user.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

if(!isExpired(getDetails(lUser.getUserId()))){

    oos.writeObject(lUser);
}

}

public String getDetails(String userId) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

String password="";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("user.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
User lUser=(User) ois.readObject();
password=lUser.getPassword();
return password;

}

 public boolean isExpired(String pass){

boolean check=false;
// your logic

return check;

}
}

class User implements Serializable{

private String userId;
private String password;

// Your setter and getter

}
```

Comment: how to possible without using the database?

Comment: Then you can persist useername/password on server in filesystem using java Serialization e.g http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/ .

Comment: can you provide me code?

Comment: @shubhanshu you want too much. Try to find it yourself.

Comment: @shubhanshu : Updated with example.